# Awk/sed command to cut on multiple delimiters

Tags: sed, awk

I have input file name as:

```
Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz
```

I want only `0000860156-001` from the file_name to append to my target file name.

Comment: Do you want to rename your `Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz` file to only `0000860156-001` or `0000860156-001.xml.gz` or something else?

Comment: What target file name? What exactly do you want to do? Do you have many `Sample_XXX.xml.gz` files? And many associated target files?

Answer (score 24):

Here are some approaches. You haven't explained what you want to do with the string you want to extract so I will just print it.

1. `awk` with multiple delimiters

   ```
   echo Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz | 
    awk -F '[_-]' '{print $2"-"$3}'
   ```
2. GNU `grep`

   ```
   echo Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz | grep -oP '_\K.*(?=-)'
   ```
3. `sed`

   ```
   echo Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz | 
     sed 's/.*_\([0-9]*-[0-9]*\)-.*/\1/'
   ```
4. Perl

   ```
   echo Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz | 
    perl -pe 's/.*_(.+?-.+?)-.*/\1/'
   ```

   Or, with recent perl versions (thanks [@ksenoy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/111534/kshenoy)):

   ```
   echo Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz | 
    perl -aF/[_-]/ -lne 'print $F[1]-$F[2]'
   ```
5. `cut`

   ```
   echo Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz | 
     cut -d_ -f2 | cut -d- -f1,2
   ```

Comment: Perl accepts a character-class as well. You could specify it as `echo Sample_0000860156-001-out_20150224150524.xml.gz | perl -aF/[_-]/ -lne 'print $F[1]-$F[2]'`

Comment: @kshenoy oh wow. when did that happen? It didn't use to and there was even a joke in the documentation that they should let awk be better at something. Cool, thanks!

Comment: Tbh, I don't know. I just checked `perl -h` and voila! it accepts a pattern now :)

Answer (score 1):

This will create a new empty file for every *.gz on the directory that **keeps the pattern of  the example**:

```
touch $(ls *.gz | awk -F '_' {'print $2'} | awk -F "-out" {'print $1'})
```

or as suggested by [Jidder](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/78605/jidder) :

```
touch $(ls *.gz | awk -F '_|-out' {'print $2'})
```

Comment: Note that this will fail if any `.gz` files in the directory contain whitespace. As a general rule, you should avoid [parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for file operations.

Comment: It won't fail, simply won't create a new file. A file with whitespace is not using the pattern.

Comment: It might be, the OP hasn't said :) He just gave a single example without explaining whether there is one or 10.000 `.gz` files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk with match

```
awk 'match($0,/_([0-9]+-[0-9]+)/,a){print "file."a[1]".gz"}' <<< "$FILENAME"
```

---

#### Ouptut

```
file.0000860156-001.gz
```