# Split a string by multiple delimeters in bash

Tags: bash, string, split

There's a string:

```
onetwothree.file.001.txt ; threefourfive.file.0.98.txt ; fivefoursix.file.14.txt
```

I want to split it by `.` and `;` removing the prefix before the filename, so that it looks like this:

```
file.001.txt ; file.0.98.txt ; file.14.txt
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help? <https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/187180/388654>

Comment: not really, because here the split is nor repeated as in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/[^.]*.//' -e 's/;[^.]*./; /g'
```

This initially removes the shortest substring up to `.` from the beginning and then can rely on `;` to operate on the resulting string.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the *"in bash"* literally, you could do something like this.

- split the string into an array, delimited by semicolons
- remove the prefix elementwise and store the result in a string, delimited by the first character of IFS
- globally add back whitespace behind the delimiters

**NOTE: you may wish to save the current `IFS` so you can restore it afterwards.**

```
IFS=";"
read -a arr <<< "onetwothree.file.001.txt ; threefourfive.file.0.98.txt ; fivefoursix.file.14.txt"
printf -v str "${arr[*]#*.}"
printf "%s\n" "${str//;/; }"
```

ginving

```
file.001.txt ; file.0.98.txt ; file.14.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, with `sed`...

```
s="onetwothree.file.001.txt ; threefourfive.file.0.98.txt ; fivefoursix.file.14.txt"
sed -E "s/(^|; )[^\.]+\./\1/g" <<<$s
```

Walkthrough

```
(^|; )[^\.]+\.
```

Find any sub-element that either starts either at the beginning of the line `^` or `|` with `;` (semicolon and a space) and which is followed by `[^\.]+\.` i.e. a continuous series which does not contain a literal `.` but which **does** end with a literal `.`

Then replace all of that with `\1` which is the capture group `(^|; )`

Output

```
file.001.txt ; file.0.98.txt ; file.14.txt
```